# more buttons, same operation, different message

Tags: android, onclick, android-button, buttonclick

I'm sorry, the title may not be easy to understand, I have to develope an application with 48 buttons. this is what a button should do:

```
checkP1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = "51aw"; 

                //add the text in the arrayList
                arrayList.add("c: " + message);

                //sends the message to the server
                if (mTcpClient != null) {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                }

                //refresh the list
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

The different thing between Button is the button's name (in this case checkP1 but others will be checkP2 checkP3 etc. ) and the message they sent.

How can I do it without write this 48 times?

thank you

Comment: Have you ever heard for loop?

Comment: How are you creating this buttons now/

Comment: 8 linear layout and the basic declaration of a button, with android studio (6buttons pro linear layout)

Answer (score 0):

Use Switch/case:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     int id=v.getId();
     switch(id) {
         case R.id.checkP1:
              String message = "51aw";
              break;

          case R.id.checkP2:
               String message = "11aa";
               break;
     }
    //add the text in the arrayList
      arrayList.add("c: " + message);

    //sends the message to the server
      if (mTcpClient != null) {
      mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```